# What is eGPU and what is it for?

Tags: graphics-cards

I consider buying Titan XP for my work on training neural net on my laptop Mac. I have never used any external GPU but as far as I investigate how to set up eGPU, it seems that I must prepare another component called *eGPU box*. For example [this blog author uses an eGPU box called Akitio Thunder3 along with GTX 1050 Ti](https://9to5mac.com/2017/04/11/hands-on-powering-the-macbook-pro-with-an-egpu-using-nvidias-new-pascal-drivers/).

However, I don't understand what is eGPU box and what is it for? Is it not possible to just buy eGPU and connect it to my laptop Mac? Do I have to buy yet another component to connect to eGPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use an *external Graphics Processing Unit* (eGPU) you (usually) need three components:

- A Thunderbold 3 cable (I will not elaborate on this one)
- A case / box that supplies power and a mount for desktop graphics cards
- A desktop graphics card that satisfies the spatial and power constraints of the box

In the blog entry the box is an Akitio Thunder3 and the graphics card is a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti. The Thunder3 provides the mount for the desktop graphics card, provides the power and the PCIe <=> Thunderbolt 3 interface and optionally also provides power for the connected laptop.

> Is it not possible to just buy eGPU and connect it to my laptop Mac?

There is no such thing as an "eGPU", the name designates the concept of using an external GPU, which is most commonly done by "faking" an internal environment to an internal GPU externally.

If you are interested in actually acquiring an eGPU solution, [egpu.io](https://egpu.io) has nice coverage, reviews, guides and overviews.

Comment: Oh I see... thanks for the clarification! So are all the eGPU setup only compatible with a machine having Thunderbolt 3? For example MacBook Pro (2016) can connect to eGPU but Mac Pro (2013) can't due to the lack of Thunderbolt 3 port?

Comment: @Blaszard Macs are special in that regard, in that they sometimes come with Thunderbolt 2 ports, if they do, you can use an eGPU. [egpu.io also has you covered in that case :)](https://egpu.io/external-gpu-buyers-guide-2017/#tb2-enclosures)

Comment: And it means that the box, not the graphic card, has a power plug that should be connected to an outlet, right?

Comment: @Blaszard exactly, the box has a plug for the outlet and the card needs to be connected to the power supply in the box.

Comment: OK, thanks. Just want to ask one more... is there such thing as "mobile eGPU", on which you don't need an outlet? I want to use eGPU on my laptop in cafe as well, if that is possible. Or does it consume too much power so unreasonable (or poor performance, if any)?

Comment: @Blaszard I don't know any such device, because a) desktop cards draw >100W usually killing every battery super quick and b) the market for such a device would be even smaller than the current desktop-powered eGPU market because most people will just get a laptop with a somewhat powerful laptop GPU instead of spending money on an external device (that they possible can't even upgrade).